# Как можно сократить код пузырьковой сортировки?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css-animation, extend

Есть код пузырьковой сортировки(не полностью). Код сортирует цифры, работает если заданы цифры в определенном порядке :7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. Если цифры поменять, код работает верно,но боксы(col,col1.....) перемещаются уже не так как надо. Как можно это исправить и возможно ли сократить код как-то? Используется библиотека jquery-3.4.1.js.

```js
var arr = [7, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]; 
document.getElementById("demo7").innerHTML = "МАССИВ ЧИСЕЛ : " +arr; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[0];
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = arr[1];
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arr[2];
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = arr[3];
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = arr[4];
document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = arr[5];
document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = arr[6];

function Animal() {
  function moveElement(arr, from, to) {
    arr.splice(to, 0, arr.splice(from, 1)[0]);
    return arr;  }
{if (arr[0] > arr[1] && arr[1] > arr[2] && arr[2] > arr[3] && arr[3] > arr[4] && arr[4] > arr[5] && arr[5] > arr[6] ) 
 document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,0,1); 
 document.getElementById("demo9").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,1,2);
 document.getElementById("demo10").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,2,3);
 document.getElementById("demo11").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,3,4);
 document.getElementById("demo12").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,4,5);
 document.getElementById("demo13").innerHTML = ' Первый шаг  '+moveElement(arr,5,6);
$( ".col1" ).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col" ).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );
$( ".col2" ).delay(2500).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col" ).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );
$( ".col3" ).delay(5000).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col" ).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );
$( ".col4" ).delay(7500).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col" ).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );
$( ".col5" ).delay(10000).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col" ).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );
$( ".col6" ).delay(12500).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col" ).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );}

{if (arr[0] > arr[1]  ) 
 document.getElementById("demo14").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,0,1); 
if (arr[1] > arr[2] )  
 document.getElementById("demo15").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,1,2);
if (arr[2] > arr[3] )  
 document.getElementById("demo16").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,2,3);
if (arr[3] > arr[4] )  
 document.getElementById("demo17").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,3,4);
if (arr[4] > arr[5] )  
 document.getElementById("demo18").innerHTML = ' Второй шаг  '+moveElement(arr,4,5);

$( ".col2" ).delay(10500).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col1" ).delay(12500).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );

$( ".col3" ).delay(11500).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col1" ).delay(2000).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );

$( ".col4" ).delay(12500).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col1" ).delay(2000).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );

$( ".col5" ).delay(15000).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col1" ).delay(2000).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );
$( ".col6" ).delay(17500).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col1" ).delay(2000).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );}

{if (arr[0] > arr[1]  ) 
 document.getElementById("demo19").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,0,1); 
if (arr[1] > arr[2] )  
 document.getElementById("demo20").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,1,2);
if (arr[2] > arr[3] )  
 document.getElementById("demo21").innerHTML = moveElement(arr,2,3);
if (arr[3] > arr[4] )  
 document.getElementById("demo22").innerHTML = ' Третий шаг  '+moveElement(arr,3,4);

$( ".col3" ).delay(14500).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col2" ).delay(17500).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 ); 

$( ".col4" ).delay(16500).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col2" ).delay(2000).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );  

$( ".col5" ).delay(16500).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col2" ).delay(2000).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );  
 
$( ".col6" ).delay(17000).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 ); 
$( ".col2" ).delay(2000).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );  
}}
var animal = new Animal();
```

```css
div {align-self: flex-end;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 1329px;
    height: 640px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    background: pink;  }
.col { 
    margin: 53px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    background: blue;  }
.col1 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 60px;
    top: 30px;
    background: yellow;  }
.col2 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 120px;
    top: 30px;
    background: red;  } 
.col3 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 180px;
    top: 30px;
    background: green;  }
.col4 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 240px;
    top: 30px;
    background: yellow;  }
.col5 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 300px;
    top: 30px;
    background: red;  } 
.col6 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 360px;
    top: 30px;
    background: green;  } 
.container1 {
   margin-top: 230px;
   margin-left: 420px;
   width:520px;
   height: 22em;
   float: left; 
   color: ; 
   background: #9999FF ;    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><table border='1'><tr><td>
<tr><td><p id ="demo7" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;text-align:center;"></p></td></tr>

<tr><td><p id ="demo8" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo9"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo10"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id ="demo11" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo12" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo13"  ></p></td></tr>

<tr><td><p id="demo14"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id ="demo15" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo16"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo17"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id ="demo18" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo19" ></p></td></tr>

<tr><td><p id="demo20"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id ="demo21" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo22"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo23"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id ="demo24" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo25" ></p></td></tr>

</table>

<div class="container1">
<div  class="col" style="margin-top:80px;" >box<p id="demo"style="font-family:Arial;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col1" style="margin-top:80px;" >box1<p id="demo1"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col2" style="margin-top:80px;"  >box2<p id="demo2"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col3" style="margin-top:80px;" >box3<p id="demo3"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col4" style="margin-top:80px;" >box4<p id="demo4"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col5" style="margin-top:80px;"  >box5<p id="demo5"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col6" style="margin-top:80px;" >box6<p id="demo6"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
```

Comment: Тут даже не `можно`, а  `нужно`... Для такого рода задач и придумали ***`циклы`***... Опиши логику перемещений,  каков должен быть конечный результат....

Answer (score -2):

Циклы вобще не знакомы? Ужас, а не код! Я поправил немного, но там с дилеями чушь какая-то, сам разбирайся, и код изначально не работает, какие-то замкнутые области с условиями.. Это он в режиме отладки? Нет уж, это больше задание, чем вопрос.

```js
var arr = [9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]; 
let demos = $('[id^="demo"]');
let cols = $('[class^="col"]');

for(let demo of demos)
{
 if (demo.id.length == 5) {
    let pop = demo.id.substr(4);
    demo.id = demo.id.slice(0, -1);
    demo.id = demo.id + '0' + pop;
  }
}
demos.sort(function(a,b){return a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1;});

demos[7].innerHTML = "МАССИВ ЧИСЕЛ : " +arr; 
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
 demos[i].innerHTML = arr[i];
}

function Animal() {
  function moveElement(arr, from, to) {
    arr.splice(to, 0, arr.splice(from, 1)[0]);
    return arr;  
  }
  if (arr[0] > arr[1] && arr[1] > arr[2] && arr[2] > arr[3] && arr[3] > arr[4] && arr[4] > arr[5] && arr[5] > arr[6] ) {
   demos[13].innerHTML = ' Первый шаг '+moveElement(arr,5,6);
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
      demos[i+8].innerHTML = moveElement(arr,i,1);
    }
    let delay = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
     cols[0].animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );
      $(cols[i+1]).delay(delay).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 );
      delay = delay + 2500;
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
      demos[i+14].innerHTML = moveElement(arr,i,1);
    }
  }
  if (arr[4] > arr[5] ) {
    demos[18].innerHTML = ' Второй шаг  '+moveElement(arr,4,5);
    let delay = 10500;
    let delayCol1 = 12500;
    for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
     cols[1].delay(delayCol1).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );
      $(cols[i+2]).delay(delay).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 );
      delay = delay + 1000;
      delayCol1 = 2000;
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
      demos[i+19].innerHTML = moveElement(arr,i,1);
    }
  }
  if (arr[3] > arr[4] ) {
    demos[22].innerHTML = ' Третий шаг  '+moveElement(arr,3,4);
  let delay = 14500;
    let delayCol2 = 17500;
    for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
     cols[2].delay(delayCol1).animate({left: "+=60"}, 2500 );
      $(cols[i+3]).delay(delay).animate({left: "-=60"}, 2500 );
      delay = delay + 1000;
      delayCol2 = 2000;
    }
  }
}
var animal = new Animal();
```

```css
div {
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 1329px;
    height: 640px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    background: pink;  
}
.col { 
    margin: 53px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    background: blue;  }
.col1 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 60px;
    top: 30px;
    background: yellow;  }
.col2 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 120px;
    top: 30px;
    background: red;  } 
.col3 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 180px;
    top: 30px;
    background: green;  }
.col4 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 240px;
    top: 30px;
    background: yellow;  }
.col5 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 300px;
    top: 30px;
    background: red;  } 
.col6 { 
    margin: 53px ;
    width: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 360px;
    top: 30px;
    background: green;  } 
.container1 {
   margin-top: 230px;
   margin-left: 420px;
   width:520px;
   height: 22em;
   float: left; 
   color: ; 
   background: #9999FF ;    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
<tr><td><p id ="demo7" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;text-align:center;"></p></td></tr>

<tr><td><p id ="demo8" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo9"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo10"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id ="demo11" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo12" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo13"  ></p></td></tr>

<tr><td><p id="demo14"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id ="demo15" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo16"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo17"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id ="demo18" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo19" ></p></td></tr>

<tr><td><p id="demo20"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id ="demo21" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo22"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo23"  ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id ="demo24" ></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p id="demo25" ></p></td></tr>

</table>

<div class="container1">
<div  class="col" style="margin-top:80px;">box<p id="demo"style="font-family:Arial;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col1" style="margin-top:80px;" >box1<p id="demo1"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col2" style="margin-top:80px;"  >box2<p id="demo2"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col3" style="margin-top:80px;" >box3<p id="demo3"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col4" style="margin-top:80px;" >box4<p id="demo4"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col5" style="margin-top:80px;"  >box5<p id="demo5"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
<div  class="col6" style="margin-top:80px;" >box6<p id="demo6"style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p></div>
```